# Error while loading sample Dashboard Data in Kibana for Packetbeat

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, packetbeat

I am new to PacketBeat and Kibana. I was following the tutorial as mentioned in  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/master/packetbeat-getting-started.html#_sample_kibana_dashboards

As per the steps, to load sample pages for Kibana while integrating with Packetbeat, I am getting below errors. Not sure why is it coming

```
curl                                                                                                                      
Loading search Cache-transactions:                                                                                        
<HEAD><TITLE>Unknown Host</TITLE></HEAD>                                                                                  
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Unknown Host</H1><HR>                                                           
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>                                                                                          
    Description: Unable to locate the server named "<em>localhost</em>" --- the server does not have a DNS entry.  Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists.  Double-check the name and try again.</B></FONT>                                                                                                                                                                                  
<HR>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        <!-- default "Unknown Host" response (504) -->                                                                                                                                                                    
 </BODY>
```

Comment: Is Elasticsearch running on the same machine where you are running the `./load.sh` command? Try giving it the full URL, something like `./load.sh http://<ip-address>:9200`, where `<ip-address>` is where Elasticsearch is listening.

Comment: @tsg: hi, it ran once i tried it with sudo. :)